# VLCJ Output audio/video modules

Tags: vmware, vlc, libvlc, vlcj, debian-based

Is there any abillity to change "Audio output module" and "Video output" in my java program?
My linux doesn't play video files when these options are set to "automatic". So in VLC Player I have chosen "ALSA" and "OpenGL GLX (XCB)", now my files are playing.
But when I use `EmbeddedMediaPlayerComponent` in my program, I think it chooses "automatic" mode for a/v threads. Then I'm getting a green screen (instead of my video) and an error in terminal:

```
[00007f691c112ac8] pulse audio output error: stream connection failure: Timeout
[00007f691c112ac8] core audio output error: module not functional
[00007f69081b6168] core decoder error: failed to create audio output
Failed to open VDPAU backend libvdpau_nvidia.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Strange, but audio is playing...
Please, help! ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the `MediaPlayerFactory` initialisation arguments to specify the name of the audio/video output module that you want to use.

Something like:

```
String[] args = {"--vout=xcb", "--aout=alsa"});
```

From a command-line, `vlc --list` will give you the available module names.

Comment: Hmm... Interesting solution, but I am afraid that I need change output "modules" in the way of my program. Such as in the VLC Player, there is a combo box where I can choose one of all available "modules". I have found `list of output devices` in vlcj, it's extremely similar to option that I'm seeking...

Comment: This answer is the only way you can do it, or at least something close to it. There is *no* API in LibVLC (and therefore vlcj) that provides a mapping of e.g. "ALSA audio output" -> "alsa", nor can it be changed on-the-fly.

Comment: You mean you doesn't provide this option in your `vlcj-player`? (I can't check this because I can't build your project :( )

Comment: vlcj can only expose what LibVLC provides. vlcj-player allows you to enumerate and select an audio device, but there is nothing for video/audio outputs as there is simply no API in LibVLC for that. And the projects build just fine using maven.